# \textsc does not make small caps

Tags: formatting, small-caps

I try to produce small caps for abbreviations like "AM" or "PM". However, this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
The flight to Krakow departs at 6:30 \textsc{AM}.
\end{document}
```

yields no small caps.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Capital letters in the small caps font are the same as in the normal font; it should be `\textsc{am}`, if you want a difference. It's better to think to the font as “caps and small caps”.

Comment: Ah, well. That makes sense. Sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees...

Comment: @egreg: If you want, you can put your comment into an answer so at least other people can benefit from my stupidity. `:-)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The font shape commonly known as “small caps” is actually *Capitals and small capitals*, meaning that uppercase letters are like the standard capital letters in the normal shape, whereas lowercase letters are *small capitals*.

So you want `\textsc{am}`, if you want reduced size of the capital letters.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the definition of small caps differs between people, it is agreed all letters are capital, but which letters do they expect to be smaller differs.
`\textsc` provides with the option where originally capital letters are large and non-capital are small. You can manually hence create the small caps you expect, I provide two automatic ways that format the way you want, wysiwym (and not the way you see).

If you want only the first letter large. You can automatically lowercase, capitalise the first letter and then use `\textsc{text}`.

Together it will look like:

```
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
% sssc - from Second Small Caps
 \newcommand{\ssc}[1]{\textsc{\capitalisewords{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ssc{text} \ssc{TEXT} % both equivalent to \textsc{Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similarly, if you want all to be small:

```
% asc - All Small Caps
\newcommand{\asc}[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\asc{text} \asc{TEXT} % both equivalent to \textsc{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel like you're answering a different question than what was asked.

Comment: Then maybe I indeed don't understand it. Didn't he want a command to have AM in capital but small letters? (the second option). I personally know SC as one big and the rest small, so I have this too for future reference (first option).

Comment: It looks like OP was missing that they needed to type `am` instead of `AM`.  Your second option would take care of that, but would hide what's going on.  And calling something `truesc` when it disregards whatever capitalization you give it seems like it would lead to long sessions of "why is this not outputting the way I expect?"

Comment: I agree it solved the writer problem to do it manually, but he expected sc to just be small and capital. The question title is also suggesting one wants \textsc to act differently as if there is a bug in it. This is also the way I got here (and probably 11K other people). I tried to make the distinction clearer in the answer.